# C++/CLI - Calling an Unmanaged Function Defined in a DLL

Tags: c++, interop, c++-cli, pinvoke

I have a DLL which contains unmanaged classes with methods. I'm trying to call those methods from C++/CLI.

My reading has lead me to find that P/Invoke is used to do this. However, I can't seem to find out how to make it work.

In the DLL, the following class is defined:

```
//Header:
namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Subtract(double a, double b);
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Multiply(double a, double b);
        static __declspec(dllexport) double Divide(double a, double b);
    };
}

//Source:
namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Divide(double a, double b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            throw new invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
        }
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

From what I've read, the following should declare a method in my C++/CLI code, which I can then call in my code:

```
class MyMathFuncs {
public:
[DllImport("TestDLL.dll")]
    static double Add(double a, double b);
};
```

Where "TestDLL.dll" is my DLL.

The error I get is at runtime. It says "Unable to find an entry point named 'Add' in DLL 'TestDLL.dll'".

What am I doing wrong? I've read through the MSDN articles on this, but I don't understand it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The unmanaged code is in a class that is in a namespace, but the managed C++ code you don't have the surrounding namespace? Could be a problem that the managed code looks for `MyMathFuncs::Add` while the DLL contains `MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add`.

Comment: Why would you use P/invoke from this. One of the nice features with C++/CLI is that you can link to native DLLs without P/invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a DEF file for your native DLL?

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh(v=vs.80).aspx

Dumpbin may also help.  See what the DLL is exporting:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c(v=vs.71).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30e78zd0(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response. According to the MSDN page you linked to, a DEF file is not needed if the __declspec(dllexport) keyword is used. I'm not sure what I would do with Dumpbin.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I need to include the EntryPoint of the function in the DLL in the DllImport attribute. However, the MSDN documentation suggests that the EntryPoint can be the function name in the DLL but this doesn't work for me - I have to state the ordinal number of the function. Can anyone let me know why this is?

Comment: Because of name mangling or name decoration. Look at the exported names of your DLL in something like Dependency Viewer. That's what the other answer is getting at but it would have been better if LemonBeagle had explicitly mentioned mangling and decoration.